# use iText to set tab order

Tags: pdf, itext, accessibility

Is it possible to set the tab order (tab follow tag structure) using iText, like Adobe Acrobat Pro does?
Using Adobe Acrobat Pro you can select a pages properties and then select between different tab order options but I need to do that programmatically.

I use OpenOffice to generate the PDFs but OpenOffice isn't capable of this option.

Comment: "Tab follows tag structure" is a requirement by nearly all screen readers and accessibility checking tools, therefore it's related to accessibility. My question is related to iText ("is it possible to set the tab order (tab follow tag structure) using iText") which is a java/c# PDF library, therefore it's a programming question.

Comment: It's a valid question for SO, and it's probably possible to add this structure to an existing PDF using low-level methods. However: this isn't available "out-of-the-box" and it would be a multiple day (maybe weeks) project to achieve this, so you probably won't get an answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I have expected ;)

Comment: @SanoJ I am pretty sure you cannot set this within iText. A few searches lead to no where, so you need to manually set it as I outlined in the other question